# knitr engine=bash. Want to set working directory separately for each chunk

Tags: r, shell, knitr

I need to write some lectures about using the shell.  I have done 100s of Sweaved R documents.  When I saw knitr had the bash engine (http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines), I used it for a test case.

This works OK, not great.  The chunks have no on-going session, every chunk evaluation starts at the working directory of the document. There's no consciousness between
chunks and so it is difficult to write about using "cd" and "pwd" in a coherent way.

I wish each chunk had an argument "working.directory".

If you know of other ways to do this, I'm all ears. At the moment, I'm exploring Emacs org mode as an alternative. It has a way to set the working directory for each chunk. But it is more difficult to style.

Here's my knitr test document,

````
---
title: "Command Line, Shell"
author:
 - name: Paul Johnson
   affiliation: Center for Research Methods and Data Analysis, University of Kansas
   email: pauljohn@ku.edu
abstract: 
    This uses knitr to interleave shell commands and output.
Note to Authors: please_dont_change_the_next 4 lines!
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y %B %d')`"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: haddock
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
outdir <- paste0("tmpout")
options("prompt" = "$ ")
options("continue" = "$ ")

if (!file.exists(outdir)) dir.create(outdir, recursive = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine="bash", echo=TRUE, comment="output:",
prompt = TRUE, fig.path=paste0(outdir, "/p-", root.dir="/tmp"))
options(width = 70)
```

## Getting Started in the Shell

### Start a Terminal Emulator
   * Mac (Utilities/Terminal, iTerm, many others)

   * Windows (Git for Windows provides a BASH shell). Others available (Cygwin, Ubuntu BASH for Windows)

   * Linux (many terminal programs, some more exciting than others)

### High points
   * Type commands, see textual output

   * Not much pointing and clicking (copy/paste possible on some)

### What is a Shell?
   * Computer has many settings that programs can access. A "shell"
     is a "behind the scenes" program that keeps those settings
     and passes them out to programs when needed
   * BASH: Bourne Again Shell, a widely-used shell
   * Almost all Unix/Mac systems will have many shell programs
     available, such as "sh", "bash", "dash", and so forth. We
     are mostly interested in BASH because it has the most user comfort
   * A terminal program relies on the shell to translate between user and operating system

#### **Prompt**. Where you type 
   * Prompt might be verbose 
```
pauljohn:Documents/Projects $
```
   * On some it is very lean, just the dollar sign
```
$
```
   * Dollar sign is customary prompt for non-root user (non-administrators)
   * Prompt is configurable, it is a good exercise for somebody who has used the Terminal for a week or two on a daily basis.

## Basic things to type

#### What is my working directory
```{r getwd}
pwd
```

```{r ls}
ls
```
See there, the output says it is still in my working directory
where the document is, not "/tmp" as requested.

The following efforts produce errors if you uncomment them.

I can't figure even how to change directory with system or Sys.setenv.

<!-- ```{r whoami5} -->
<!-- system("cd /tmp") -->
<!-- ls -->
<!-- ``` -->



<!-- ```{r whoami6} -->
<!-- Sys.setenv(PWD = "/tmp") -->
<!-- ls -->
<!-- ``` -->
````

Comment: Most non-R sessions in knitr are not persistent, so `cd` will not be carried through following bash chunks. Please see https://github.com/yihui/runr for another possibility.

Comment: Hi @Yihui. I will try runr.  Your comments about it on the knitr page are not too enthusiastic.

Comment: Sorry for the distraction. I found a workable answer and posted it below.  Could you be kind enough to tell us if there will be flaws due to running opts_knitr several times to change root.dir between bash chunks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution. It does not achieve a persistent BASH session, but it achieves the same workaround that can be had with Emacs org-mode. It allows one to set the working directory separately for various code BASH chunks. That is almost as good as having a persistent shell session.

HOWTO? Use knitr::opts_knitr in engine="R" code chunks to reset root.dir between chunks when a change of working directory is required. Following bash chunks respect the new setting.

Only @Yihui can tell us if this causes dangers in cache and such; there are strong warnings about setwd within R chunks.

Here is example that does work, first starting with a working directory "/tmp" and then my home directory "~".

````
---
title: "Command Line, Shell"
author:
 - name: Paul Johnson
   affiliation: Center for Research Methods and Data Analysis, University of Kansas
   email: pauljohn@ku.edu
abstract: 
    This uses knitr to interleave shell commands and output.
Note to Authors: please_dont_change_the_next 4 lines!
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y %B %d')`"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: haddock
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
outdir <- paste0("tmpout")
options("prompt" = "$ ")
options("continue" = "$ ")

if (!file.exists(outdir)) dir.create(outdir, recursive = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine="bash", echo=TRUE, comment="output:",
prompt = TRUE, fig.path=paste0(outdir, "/p-"))
options(width = 70)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir="/tmp")
```

## Basic things to type

#### What is my working directory. These are BASH chunks, not R chunks!
```{r getwd}
pwd
```

```{r ls}
ls
```

Here is how I change directory for following bash chunks.
Note engine = bash in this document, so we set R 
engine just for this one

```{r, engine = "R"}
opts_knit$set(root.dir="~")
```

```{r ls2}
ls
```
````

I just uploaded the html output as evidence that this does compile:

http://pj.freefaculty.org/scraps/test_dummy.html